# How to read vector in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, combinatorics

I have used "combinatoricslib" to Generate combination from a object array. But the result is displayed as a vector. I want to know how to read only one value.

Here is the code.

```
// Create the initial vector
   ICombinatoricsVector<String> initialVector = Factory.createVector(
      new String[] { "red", "black", "white", "green", "blue" } );

   // Create a simple combination generator to generate 3-combinations of the initial vector
   Generator<String> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, 3);

   // Print all possible combinations
   for (ICombinatoricsVector<String> combination : gen) {
      System.out.println(combination);
   }
```

This is the result.

```
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, black, white], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, black, green], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, black, blue], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, white, green], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, white, blue], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([red, green, blue], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([black, white, green], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([black, white, blue], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([black, green, blue], size=3)
   CombinatoricsVector=([white, green, blue], size=3)
```

But it has both combination array and size. But i want to get only the array. how to get it.
Please help me. I am new to java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to read the javadoc. It took me 5 seconds to google it and find it: http://combinatoricslib.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release21/doc/org/paukov/combinatorics/ICombinatoricsVector.html

> `java.util.List<T> getVector()`
>
> Returns vector as a list of elements

Answer (score 1):

I understand that what you're using here is an instance of [`combinatorics.CombinatoricsVector`](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/source/browse/trunk/src/combinatorics/CombinatoricsVector.java)

It has a `getVector` method, which returns a `List` of all the elements in a vector like this (in this case, all the colours) and a `getValue(int index)` method, which allows you to retrieve an object at a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Generator<String> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, 3);

// Print all possible combinations
for (ICombinatoricsVector<String> combination : gen) {
    System.out.println(combination.getValue(0)); // This gets the first value from the vector
    System.out.println(combination.iterator().next()); // This is another way to do it
}
```

Check the [Javadoc](http://combinatoricslib.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release21/doc/org/paukov/combinatorics/CombinatoricsVector.html) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this will work well for you:

```
   // Print all possible combinations
   for (ICombinatoricsVector<String> combination : gen) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination.toArray()));
   }
```

Comment: There is no toArray() method in the ICombinatoricsVector interface. Read the javadoc.